# Cannot resolve symbol resolved elsewhere

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This might be a very simple question but I can't seem to find the answer so any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Android studio to develop an Android app and I'm having a problem with one of my dependecies. 
The method I'm using is not recognized everywhere : as you can see in the screenshot, I try to invoque the getInstance method of BeanManager (defined in nl.littlerobots.bean.BeanManager) in one part of my code but the method is not recognized, whereas it works without success a few lines earlier. When I copy-paste the line with the error and put it inside the onBeanDiscovered() it works, but when I paste it in the new BeanDiscoveryListener declaration it doesn't work either.
I've tried cleaning the project but it doesn't change anything

What am I missing ?

[image: The error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehrm your method call `BeanManager.getInstance().cancelDiscovery()` needs to be wrapped inside a method since it's a statement. That's nothing special about Android Studio or any other IDE it's just a *"Java thing"*.

So for example something like this would totally work:

```
private void someMethod(){
    BeanManager.getInstance().cancelDiscovery();
}
```

Comment: And here's to me feeling totally stupid ! Thanks a lot .. if you allow me I'd like to go hide in shame now ...